# Homemade php function seems to add unwanted whitespace

Tags: php, html

I have an esthetic problem that annoys me no end: the following function reshuffles names that are in a mysql table as

> "Lastname, Firstname (something)"

into

> "Firstname Lastname"

(e.g. "Lennon, John" becomes "John Lennon".

```
<?php
function rearrangeName($name){
    $cut = strpos($name, "("); //locate position of opening bracket if 
        //there is one
    if($cut != ""){
        $name_without_brackets = substr($name, 0, $cut-1);//throw away 
        //stuff between brackets
    }
    else{
        $name_without_brackets = $name;
    }
    $komma = strpos($name_without_brackets, ","); //see if there are commas
    if($komma == FALSE){
        $newName = $name_without_brackets;
    }
    else{
        $newName1 = explode(", ", $name_without_brackets);//split
            //$name_without_brackets and put First name before Last name
        $newName = ($newName1[1] . "&nbsp" . $newName1[0]);
    }
    print $newName;
}
?>
```

A similar function returns only last names. They work fine but apparently add whitespace so that when I use them inside other functions to diplay songs with their songwriters between brackets the result is not what I want. Instead of

`(Lennon & McCartney), (John Lennon) and (Harrison, Lennon, McCartney, Starr)`

I get

`( Lennon & McCartney ), ( John Lennon) and ( Harrison , Lennon , McCartney , Starr )`

Whitespace galore, except for one at the end of "John Lennon". If not for that missing extra whitespace I might not even have noticed it.

I've looked left, right and center for solutions but found none that worked. Tried trim at every possible level: didn't work. Tried removing every tab or line break present: didn't work. Tried fiddling with the css: didn't work.

Can the problem be that I'm using this function inside a link? (Not that I've found any pointers in that direction, but I thought I'd just mention it.)

At the request of *Stiliyan* (see below), here's some more background info.

The second rearrange function goes like this:

```
    <?php
function rearrangeName2($name){
    $cut = strpos($name, "("); //locate position of opening bracket if 
        //there is one
    if($cut != ""){
        $name_without_brackets = substr($name, 0, $cut-1);//throw away 
             //stuff between brackets
    }
    else{
        $name_without_brackets = $name;
    }

    $newName1 = explode(", ", $name_without_brackets);//split
       // $name_without_brackets and only keep Last Name
    $newName = $newName1[0];
    print $newName;
}
?>
```

Both functions are called inside this next one:

```
<?php
function songwriter($songId){ //for one, two or many authors
    include 'connect_to_database.php';

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Author_ID, Artist FROM
    songs_with_authors, artists
     WHERE Author_ID = artists.ID 
     AND Song_ID =" . $songId . "
     ORDER BY Artist");
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);    
     if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 2){ ?>//
            <a href="results_by_author.php?nummer=<?php echo
            $row['Author_ID']; ?>">
            <?php rearrangeName2($row['Artist']); ?></a>
            <?php $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            echo " &amp; "; ?>
            <a href="results_by_author.php?nummer=<?php echo  
            $row['Author_ID']; ?>">
            <?php rearrangeName2($row['Artist']); ?></a>
            <?php
        }
        else{ ?>
            <a href="results_by_author.php?nummer=<?php echo 
            $row['Author_ID']; ?>">
            <?php rearrangeName2($row['Artist']); ?></a>
                <?php $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                while ($row){
                    echo ", "; ?>
                    <a href="results_by_author.php?nummer=<?php echo 
                    $row['Author_ID']; ?>">
                    <?php rearrangeName2($row['Artist']); ?></a>
                <?php $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                }
            }
    }
    else{ ?>
        <a href="results_by_author.php?nummer=<?php echo $row['Author_ID'];  
            ?>">
            <?php rearrangeName($row['Artist']); ?></a><?php
    }
}
?>
```

The date tables used, look like this: First the "artists" table:

```
ID    Artist 
1     Lennon, John 
2     McCartney, Paul
3     Harrison, George
4     Starr, Ringo
```

And this is the "songs_with_authors" table:

```
ID    Song_ID    Author_ID
36    355        1
37    355        2
38    355        3
39    355        4
40    356        1
41    356        2
```

Author_ID in the songs_with_authors table refers to ID in the artists table; Song_ID refers to ID in a songlist table.

The songwriter function is called in a separate page that creates a tracklisting with titles of songs and, between brackets, their authors and that page is included in another page that shows details of LP's or CD's. However the problem of the unwanted whitespace already occurs when I call the songwriter function in an empty page with just a Song_ID as its argument. E.g. songwriter(355) gives " Harrison , Lennon , McCartney , Starr ". (With ugly spaces before commas.) Because it also occurs in a completely different setting where I show a list of composers on classical records, where an extra space sometimes causes slashes to appear at the beginning of a line regardless of a &nbsp, I thought the rearrange functions must be the culprits.

Comment: it would be awesome if those variables are readable :D or translated in eng

Comment: @Ceeee just be dutch like the rest of us, kidding: you're right.

Comment: @guy13 ^ Also, could you provide sample input?

Comment: @Stiliyan Lennon, John -> John Lennon

Comment: It looks like your code is fine, and that the names in your data sometimes contain extra spaces. Could you show us at which levels you've tried trimming? Because it seems to me that this is the way to solve it.

Comment: For better answer, you can provide three different input example (including failed)

Comment: translated  "herschiknaam" to english using google translate and it is translated to ....."herschiknaam" .......... sigh

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but the easiest solution by far would be to use 3 fields in the database for `firstname`, `lastname` and `something`.

Comment: luckily i understand dutch. Why don't you trim the output ? When i test your function it works ok without any spaces? Do you have a example name that goes through the function ?

Comment: Compound:  herschik-naam: rearrange name

Comment: @Ceeee "knip" = cut; "naam zonder haakjes" = name without brackets (throws out the part between brackets if there is one); "komma" = comma; "nieuwe naam" = new name... Oh and "herschik naam" = rearrange name  (o:

Comment: @Glubus Checked the data table: no extra spaces in the "Lennon, John" field. Removed the space between the comma and "John" in the table and the one in the explode function. Still get "( John Lennon)", that is with a space before John and not after Lennon.

Comment: What you can do is break down the function. print_r() every piece and exit; it  to see where it goes wrong

Comment: Provide information about all possible formats of input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the newlines and other whitespaces you have between your anchor tags and your `php` tags in the `songwriter` function. Here is what the output looks like with the whitespaces:

```html
<a href="results_by_author.php?nummer=1">
        Lennon</a>
            ,                 <a href="results_by_author.php?nummer=2">
                McCartney</a>
            ,                 <a href="results_by_author.php?nummer=3">
                Harrison</a>
```

Browsers condense the extra whitespace into a single interval, which then shows up in the output.

To fix it and avoid problems with whitespace in the future, open your `<?php` tags right after your html tags like so:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 2){ ?>
        <a href="results_by_author.php?nummer=<?php
            echo $row['Author_ID']; ?>"><?php // no whitespace before tag
            rearrangeName2($row['Artist']); 
        ?></a><?php

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        echo " &amp; ";
        ?><a href="results_by_author.php?nummer=<?php
            echo $row['Author_ID']; ?>"><?php // no whitespace before tag
            rearrangeName2($row['Artist']); ?></a><?php
    } 
    else { ?>
        <a href="results_by_author.php?nummer=<?php
            echo $row['Author_ID']; ?>"><?php // no whitespace before tag
        rearrangeName2($row['Artist']); ?></a><?php
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        while ($row) {
            echo ", "; ?>
            <a href="results_by_author.php?nummer=<?php
                echo $row['Author_ID']; ?>"><?php // no whitespace before tag
            rearrangeName2($row['Artist']); ?></a><?php
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it but unfortunately it makes no difference to the outcome.

Comment: It looks like the problem is at a different level in your call chain. Please follow the steps here until you isolate all the minimal source code required to reproduce the problem completely: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Added requested code: see top. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @guy13 - just updated based on the new information. Your intuition about the anchors was correct! Just have to be mindful of the whitespaces before your `<?php` tags.

Comment: Stiliyan, thanks a million. This solved at least this problem and no doubt put me on the right track for the slash problem I mentioned above. Thought I tried it before but probably did it the wrong way. Tried to remove the one instance you left at the end of line 2: couldn't do it because the edit was less than 6 characters. Anyway, too embarrassed to say how long this has been staring me in the face.

Comment: You're welcome and good luck resolving the problem with the slashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
print str_replace(' ', $nieuwenaam);
```

Comment: That will result in JohnLennon I imagine (pun intended)

Comment: I don't think this is correct syntax either as str_replace always takes 3 arguments (if Im correct). @mplungjan you're not the only one in your suspicion.

Comment: I was thinking to use it on the last names function

Comment: That would be on both ` $nieuwenaam1[1] . "&nbsp" . $nieuwenaam1[0]`

Comment: @FedericoSosa last names can still have spaces in them and your use of the function is also incorrect.

Comment: some last name like "Del Rosario", or "El toro" haha

Answer (score 1):

Would this be what you are looking for?

```
function herschikNaam($naam) {
    // If name contains any parenthesis, snip until right before
    if (strpos($naam, '(') !== false)
        $naam = substr($naam, 0, (strpos($naam, '(')-1));

    $naam = explode(',', $naam);
    // If there's a comma, reorder them.
    if (count($naam) === 2) 
        return trim($naam[1]) . ' ' . trim($naam[0]);
    // No comma, give it back in same order
    else 
        return implode(' ', $naam);
}
```

It seems to do what you want when provided with e.g. "Lennon, John", "Lennon & McCartney"

Comment: Thanks for the effort but unfortunately it doesn't do the trick. There's even no result at all for John Lennon anymore. BTW for Lennon & McCartney the input is pulled from two lines in the data table "Lennon, John" and "McCartney, Paul".